# Delete ListView entry on button click - Android

Tags: java, android

I have custom listview that has a list view and button. I want to delete the entry of the listview whose button is clicked. But my app keeps crashing because the button removes items from the array but does not update the view. The app crashes when the array is empty. 
This is what i have:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ComplainDetailsAdvisorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complain_details_advisor);

        final String[] foods = {"Bacon", "Ham", "Tuna", "Candy", "Meatball", "Potato"};


        final ListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,foods);// Pass the food array to the constructor.
        ListView customListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.complainList);
        customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);}}
```

CustomAdapterClass:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    ArrayList<String> foods;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] foods) {
        super(context, R.layout.customrow, foods);
        this.foods=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(foods));;
    }

    public void refreshFoods(ArrayList<String> foods) {
        this.foods.clear();
        this.foods.addAll(foods);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myCustomInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myCustomInflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow, parent, false);
        String singleFoodItem = getItem(position);
        TextView itemText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.adComplain);

        itemText.setText(singleFoodItem);

        Button b2 = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.resolveButton);
        b2.setTag(position);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ((ViewGroup) arg0.getParent()).removeView(arg0);
                int pos = (int)arg0.getTag();
                foods.remove(pos);
                refreshFoods((ArrayList<String>) foods.clone());

                CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();            }
        });

        return customView;
    }
}
```

XML for ComplainDetailsAdvisorActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/complainList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

XML for custom row in listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resolveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/resolve_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adComplain"
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/adVotes"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adVotes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: this is the error log

```
2018-12-08 19:27:20.816 719-719/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.mariaahmed.sas'!
2018-12-08 19:27:22.304 719-719/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.mariaahmed.sas'!
2018-12-08 19:27:28.503 9745-9745/? E/SPPClientService: [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName : com.example.mariaahmed.sas, true, false
2018-12-08 19:27:29.053 27395-27395/com.example.mariaahmed.sas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mariaahmed.sas, PID: 27395
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
        at com.example.mariaahmed.sas.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11202)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23985)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
2018-12-08 19:27:31.093 27791-27808/? E/AASAservice-TokenRule: parseToken() : TokenFile is null
2018-12-08 19:27:31.162 27791-27808/? E/AASAservice-IntentThread: AASAIntentThread : myrule is null.
```

Comment: Please, upload the logs with the errors when the app crashes.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing the `clone()`, `clear()`, `addAll()` routine, but all you really need to do is `remove()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @when I remove those methods and only use `remove()`, `notifyDataSetChanged()` the app still crashes.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see it now. You're keeping a `List` separate from what `ArrayAdapter` is keeping internally when you pass the `String[]` to it in the `super` constructor. Don't keep a separate `ArrayList` yourself. Create your `ArrayList` first, and pass that in your `CustomAdapter` constructor, and then to the `super` constructor. Then, to remove, just do `remove(getItem(pos));`. You don't even need the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call for that.

Comment: @MikeM. Thankyou! That works! :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to override get counts method and return the size of foods arraylist.

Comment: This will just create a different issue. The `foods` `List` is still a separate `List` from what `ArrayAdapter` is keeping internally. Even with this overide, removing from `foods` does not remove from `ArrayAdapter`'s internal `List`, so no matter which item you remove from `foods`, it will just display one less of the original array, in order, looking like the last item is always the one removed. Did you happen to read the comments on the question?